# Select element in css with nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I am trying to select below element

`<button name="1" id="1" class="btn1 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>` in CSS, but it wont work. Is it possible with this way or should I make it with the conservative way with dots?

**Code snippet**

```css
@keyframes example {
  100% {
    background-color: grey;
  }
}
div > button:nth-child(1) {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-theme="a" data-role="page" data-url="/soc/gamescreen.php" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 499px;">
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <button name="1" id="1" class="btn1 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button name="2" id="2" class="btn2 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <button name="3" id="3" class="btn3 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button name="4" id="4" class="btn4 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use the ID (which ideally, should not be a number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code `div > button:nth-child(1)` will select all the buttons since they are the first child of their respective parent element.

I am not sure why you can't use the ID element(by escaping the number character using `\3`) to select your element but if you want to select with respect to `:nth-child`, you can try it like below.

```css
@keyframes example {
  100% {
    background-color: grey;
  }
}

/* Select the first grid a and then select the button under block a */

.ui-grid-a:first-child .ui-block-a > button { 
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-theme="a" data-role="page" data-url="/soc/gamescreen.php" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 499px;">
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <button name="1" id="1" class="btn1 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button name="2" id="2" class="btn2 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <button name="3" id="3" class="btn3 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button name="4" id="4" class="btn4 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I accept your answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: Take your time to accept it, but just check this article: https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/ Tells how to escape the ID numbers and good practices.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the button by id too; but you need to [escape the selector](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes):

```css
button {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 4em;
  height: 1em;
}
button#\31 {
  background-color: red;
}
button#\000032 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-theme="a" data-role="page" data-url="/soc/gamescreen.php" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 499px;">
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <button name="1" id="1" class="btn1 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button name="2" id="2" class="btn2 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <button name="3" id="3" class="btn3 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button name="4" id="4" class="btn4 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that it too a nice solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.ui-grid-a:first-child div:first-child > button { 
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

But I'm wondering why you don't select it by id. You already assign it an id, just rename an id without using only numbers:

```
<button name="1" id="btn1" class="btn1 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>
```

And then, it should be as simple as:

```
#btn1 {
   animation-name: example;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
```